# loop through a json object in ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am new to json so i am getting a json reponse from my ajax call

now i am stuck with looping the json object

here is my json

```
 {
    "0": {
        "image": "http://test.com/systems.jpg",
        "anchor_tag_link": "http://test.com/1",
        "title": "Oct-Dec-2013"
    },
    "1": {
        "image": "http://test.com/energy.jpg",
        "anchor_tag_link": "http://test.com/1",
        "title": "July-Sept-2013"
    },
    "pages": 2
}
```

Can anyone help

Comment: $array = json_decode("json string",true); ?? Then loop the array

Comment: is it an object or string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a for-in loop as follows:

```
var obj = {
  "0": {
    "image": "http://test.com/systems.jpg",
    "anchor_tag_link": "http://test.com/1",
    "title": "Oct-Dec-2013"
},
"1": {
    "image": "http://test.com/energy.jpg",
    "anchor_tag_link": "http://test.com/1",
    "title": "July-Sept-2013"
},
"pages": 2
}

for(var prop in obj) {
    var item = obj[prop];
    console.log(item);
}
```

Be aware that you will get the items in your log because you will get the `pages` property in addition to the numeric properties.

Comment: hi thanks for your response, i am getting an error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 540 of the JSON data

Comment: my mistake i had missed a semicolon on the servser side code. anyways it works fine.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Save your JSON response in a variable

```
var variable = {
    "0" : {
        "image" : "http://test.com/systems.jpg",
        "anchor_tag_link" : "http://test.com/1",
        "title" : "Oct-Dec-2013"
    },
    "1" : {
        "image" : "http://test.com/energy.jpg",
        "anchor_tag_link" : "http://test.com/1",
        "title" : "July-Sept-2013"
    },
    "pages" : 2
};
```

Then loop it using jquery

```
$.each(variable, function(index, value) {
    alert(value.image);
    alert(value.anchor_tag_link);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this.

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);// here data is your response
    for (var key in json) {

    alert(json[key].image);// other also in the same way.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Example 1 :

```
 success: function(responseData) {
        for (var key in responseData) {
            alert(responseData[key]);
        }
    }
```

Example 2 :

```
<script>
    var data = '{"name": "mkyong","age": 30,"address": {"streetAddress": "88 8nd Street","city": "New York"},"phoneNumber": [{"type": "home","number": "111 111-1111"},{"type": "fax","number": "222 222-2222"}]}';
    var json = JSON.parse(data);

    alert(json["name"]); //mkyong
    alert(json.name); //mkyong

    alert(json.address.streetAddress); //88 8nd Street
    alert(json["address"].city); //New York

    alert(json.phoneNumber[0].number); //111 111-1111
    alert(json.phoneNumber[1].type); //fax

    alert(json.phoneNumber.number); //undefined
</script>
```

[Sample Code](http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-access-json-object-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code. You only have to replace "yourJSONObject" by the JSON array.

```
    $.each( yourJSONObject, function( keyImg, valImg ) {
            image = valImg[0];
            anchor_tag_link = valImg[1];
            title = valImg[2];
    });
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through this like looping through javascript object :

```
   for(var arg in object) {
     object.hasOwnProperty(arg) {
       process(object[arg]); 
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JQuery:
var JSON = {
"0": {
    "image": "http://test.com/systems.jpg",
    "anchor_tag_link": "http://test.com/1",
    "title": "Oct-Dec-2013"
},
"1": {
    "image": "http://test.com/energy.jpg",
    "anchor_tag_link": "http://test.com/1",
    "title": "July-Sept-2013"
},
"pages": 2
};

if(JSON.pages >0)
{
   for(var i=0; i<JSON.pages; i++)
   {
    $('table').append('<tr><td>'+JSON[i].title+'</td><td>'+JSON[i].image+'</td><td>'+JSON[i].anchor_tag_link+'</td></tr>');
   }
}

HTML:
<table border="1"></table>
```